# How to get output in p tag?

Tags: javascript

Why this code doesn't get any outputs in p Tag?
Please explain it

```
const inputName = document.getElementById("inputName");
const btnShow = document.getElementById("btnShow");
const pShow = document.getElementById("pShow");

btnShow.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const text = inputName.Value;
  pShow.textContent = text;
});
console.log(inputName, btnShow, pShow);
```

Comment: It was my problem too , did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input elements have `value` property and not `Value`, do it like this:

```js
const inputName = document.getElementById("inputName");
const btnShow = document.getElementById("btnShow");
const pShow = document.getElementById("pShow");

btnShow.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const text = inputName.value;
  pShow.textContent = text;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputName">
<button id="btnShow">Click Me!</button>

<p id="pShow"></p>
```